# Добавление в БД mysql текста с форматированием

Tags: php, html, mysql

Пользователи в поле вбивают какой-то текст. Естественно где-то расставляют переносы и прочее. 
в Базу данных же попадает голый текст без всякого форматирования. 
И при последующем выводе данного текста без базы он пойдет в одну строчку. 
Как сделать так, чтобы в базу шел html код (автоматически сгенерированный), а не просто текст.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используйте [htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/htmlentities) Для добавления в базу, и при выводе из нее используйте [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)